# Does Swift's Combine framework have a sample(on:) operator similar to those in RXSwift or Reactive Swift?

Tags: rx-swift, reactive, sample, combine

Does anyone know how to recreate sampling behavior in Combine?

Here's a diagram of the sample's behavior in RXMarbles

[image]

The gist of sample() is that there are two streams, when one is triggered, the latest value of the other stream is sent if it already hasn't been sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CombineExt](https://github.com/CombineCommunity/CombineExt) library has the `withLatestFrom` operator which does what you want, along with many other useful operators.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Playground that **might** do what you want.  I didn't do a whole lot of testing on it so please proceed with caution:

```
import UIKit
import Combine
import PlaygroundSupport

struct SamplePublisher<DataSeq, Trigger, E> : Publisher
where DataSeq : Publisher,
      Trigger : Publisher,
      DataSeq.Failure == Trigger.Failure,
      E == DataSeq.Failure,
      DataSeq.Output : Equatable {

    typealias Output = DataSeq.Output
    typealias Failure = E

    // The two sequences we are observing, the data sequence and the
    // trigger sequence.  When the trigger fires it will send the
    // latest value from the dataSequence UNLESS it hasn't changed
    let dataPublisher : DataSeq
    let triggerPublisher : Trigger

    struct SamplePublisherSubscription : Subscription {
        var combineIdentifier = CombineIdentifier()

        let dataSubscription : AnyCancellable
        let triggerSubscription : Subscription

        func request(_ demand: Subscribers.Demand) {
            triggerSubscription.request(demand)
        }

        func cancel() {
            dataSubscription.cancel()
            triggerSubscription.cancel()
        }
    }

    func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, E == S.Failure, DataSeq.Output == S.Input {
        var latestData : DataSeq.Output?
        var lastSent : DataSeq.Output?
        var triggerSubscription : Subscription?

        // Compares the latest value sent to the last one that was sent.
        // If they don't match then it sends the latest value along.
        // IF they do match, or if no value has been sent on the data stream yet
        // Don't emit a new value.
        func emitIfNeeded() -> Subscribers.Demand {
            guard let latest = latestData else { return .unlimited }

            if nil == lastSent ||
                lastSent! != latest {
                lastSent = latest
                return subscriber.receive(latest)
            } else {
                return .unlimited
            }
        }

        // Here we watch the data stream for new values and simply
        // record them.  If the data stream ends, or erors we
        // pass that on to our subscriber.
        let dataSubscription = dataPublisher.sink(
            receiveCompletion: {
                switch $0 {
                    case .finished:
                        subscriber.receive(completion: .finished)
                    case .failure(let error):
                        subscriber.receive(completion: .failure(error))
                }
            },
            receiveValue: {
                latestData = $0
            })

        // The thing that subscribes to the trigger sequence.
        // When it receives a value, we emit the latest value from the data stream (if any).
        // If the trigger stream ends or errors, that will also end or error this publisher.
        let triggerSubscriber = AnySubscriber<Trigger.Output,Trigger.Failure>(
            receiveSubscription: { subscription in triggerSubscription = subscription },
            receiveValue: { _ in emitIfNeeded() },
            receiveCompletion: {
                switch $0 {
                    case .finished :
                        emitIfNeeded()
                        subscriber.receive(completion: .finished)
                    case .failure(let error) :
                        subscriber.receive(completion: .failure(error))
                }
            })

        // subscribe to the trigger sequence
        triggerPublisher.subscribe(triggerSubscriber)

        // Record relevant information and return the subscription to the subscriber.
        subscriber.receive(subscription: SamplePublisherSubscription(
            dataSubscription: dataSubscription,
            triggerSubscription: triggerSubscription!))
    }
}

extension Publisher {

    // A utility function that lets you create a stream that is triggered by
    // a value being emitted from another stream
    func sample<Trigger, E>(trigger: Trigger) -> SamplePublisher<Self, Trigger, E>
    where Trigger : Publisher,
          Self.Failure == Trigger.Failure,
          E == Self.Failure,
    Self.Output : Equatable {
        return SamplePublisher( dataPublisher : self, triggerPublisher : trigger)
    }
}

var count = 0
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 5.0, on: RunLoop.current, in: .common).autoconnect().eraseToAnyPublisher()
let data = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: RunLoop.current, in: .common)
    .autoconnect()
    .scan(0) { total, _ in total + 1}


var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
data.sample(trigger: timer).print()
    .sink(receiveCompletion: {
        debugPrint($0)
    }, receiveValue: {
        debugPrint($0)
    }).store(in: &subscriptions)

PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```